# How to Completely Uninstall Visual Studio Code with Its Settings and Reinstall?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cygwin

I really messed up with vs code settings. Everything set up to Cygwin's things. I deleted Cygwin and installed other compilers. But every time it's giving errors like can't reach the terminal cygwin/bash not found etc. How can I get rid of it and make a clean install?